Why is my dynamically generated HTML content not appearing in the React component?
I'm building a React application where I need to insert some HTML content dynamically based on user interactions. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ContentDisplay() {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');

    const generateContent = () => {
        const newContent = '<p>This is a dynamically generated paragraph.</p>';
        setContent(newContent);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={generateContent}>Generate Content</button>
            <div>{content}</div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContentDisplay;

I expected the HTML content to be rendered inside the div after clicking the button, but instead, it just displays the HTML as a string. How can I make the dynamically generated content appear as actual HTML rather than plain text?

This is expected behavior, it's a mechanism by React to avoid injecting HTML values from user input. Malicious users can use this to do XSS Attacks.
If you really want to do this, and have control over how the markup you can do this:
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ContentDisplay() {
    const [content, setContent] = useState('');

    const generateContent = () => {
        const newContent = '<p>This is a dynamically generated paragraph.</p>';
        setContent(newContent);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={generateContent}>Generate Content</button>
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content}} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default ContentDisplay;


